# Font editing buttons disappeared

Tags: mailing

The font editing buttons have disappeared from the New Mailings message box following a recent upgrade - is there a setting somewhere where I can turn these back on? Our test environment is still working fine.

Comment: may not relate, but always worth clearing templates_c folder

Comment: also mention what you upgraded from

Answer (score 2):

Can you check ckeditor settings under Display Preference ( Civicrm > Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preference)